# Is it possible to sync your Exchange/Outlook calendar with an Android application?

Tags: calendar, exchange

I have decided to install CloudMagic to be able to receive Exchange e-mail on my Android phone without having to accept restricted company security settings. There are many e-mail clients that support Exchange without enforcing company security settings.

I was wondering if there are also Android applications that can just make the Exchange calendar available?

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to get this to work on an Acer Z200:

1. Click the *Settings* wheel
2. Under *ACCOUNTS*, select *Corporate*
3. Add your Exchange account there and set its sync options

I now see my Exchange email and calendars in the standard Calendar app, and I get notifications for my Exchange calendar appointments.

Before doing that, I installed Microsoft's Outlook app and added my Exchange account as an account of type *Outlook*. This allows me to view my email and calendars in the Outlook app, but I didn't find a way to make it send notifications for calendar items. (If it is possible, please correct this answer.)

Comment: Please indicate what version of Android you are using on your device.

Comment: What it came with: Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many apps out there which can sync your exchange calendar with your android device. But most of the easier and more elegant software are paid-for apps. The only good enough free app I could find is this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.mp.calendar.sync

Comment: Good but it doesn't support OWA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Team Calendar Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamsite.android.calendar.generated) to sync an Exchange server locally to my Android devices.

For Outlook.com, you can try [TouchDown for Outlook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.outlook.nitroid).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built-in email app, you can get you calendar on your phone. When you are setting it up, just untick sync email, contacts and your calendar will appear invite default calendar app on your device. You can purchase calendar apps that will only sync your calendar, but the are about €9/$9/£9 so your best option is use the default app.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution is :

1. Setup your Exchange account and enable all syncing (email, calendar, contacts)
2. Go into settings -> apps -> all apps
3. Clear cache and data from the following apps :

   -Exchange-services

   -Gmail
4. Restart calendar app and the exchange account is now visible in the list of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Install the App "nine" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninefolders.hd3&hl=de
There you can choose what to sync before the first sync and you can just enable the calendar sync.